# Linux Powershell client

Tags: windows, linux, powershell, ssh

As I know, I can connect to remote Windows server through SSH from Linux and use Powershell. But how I can connect without ssh from linux? Maybe exists native tools?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a remote desktop session, you could use the `rdesktop` package:

```
Description: RDP client for Windows NT/2000 Terminal Server
 rdesktop is an open source client for Windows NT/2000 Terminal Server, capable
 of natively speaking its Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) in order to present
 the user's NT/2000 desktop. Unlike Citrix ICA, no server extensions are
 required.
```

I'm unaware of any other native Windows protocols similar in spirit to `ssh`.

I guess you could install a VNC daemon on your Windows system so you could use VNC clients on your Linux boxes. Or you could install (well, no, *please don't*) a Windows `telnet` daemon, and use `telnet` to connect. Or you could install Citrix on your Windows server and use the Linux Citrix client. (Not a solution I enjoyed using in the past. I'd recommend sticking with `ssh` or VNC instead.)

Comment: Ок. I installed FreeSSHd and run into it PS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a shell you can try [winexe](http://winexe.sourceforge.net)

it works quite well on fedora